# Matrix multiplication in game theory doesn't add up? Min y^T*Ax

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, game-theory

I'm studying game theory and something seems weird to me.

My book says y is the probability of the row player and x is the probability of column player, both x and y are vectors.

A = [a$_i$$_j$] is the payout matrix, if a$_i$$_j$ is positive, column player pays the row player and vice versa.

So the the row player would want to minimize his payouts giving us

min y$^T$Ax with some constraint.

My question is that when I did the matrix multiplication, it dimensions do not add up.

[image]

Am I missing something??

Comment: $y$ is a column vector, so $y^T$ is a row vector.  The result should be a scalar.

Comment: Oh, duh. For some reason, I thought all vectors were row vectors. Thanks!

Comment: One more question. After I multiply out y$^T$Ax i get -1/9. What does this number mean?

Comment: That is the expected payout, given mixed strategies specified in the $x$ and $y$ vectors.

Comment: So positive means row player pays the column player?